# System.IO.Stream does not contain definition for CopyTo()

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, .net-2.0

Hi I am getting the error "

> 'System.IO.Stream' does not contain a definition for 'CopyTo' and no
>   extension method 'CopyTo' accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.IO.Stream' could be found (are you missing a using directive
>   or an assembly reference?)

"
  I am using following lines of code in my project.

```
Bitmap img;
 using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
 {
    fu.PostedFile.InputStream.CopyTo(ms);
    ms.Position = 0;
    img = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(ms);
 }
```

Why I am getting this error? How to solve this?
Please help me...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stream.CopyTo was introduced in .NET 4. Since you're targeting .Net 2.0, it's not available. Internally, `CopyTo` is mainly doing this (although has extra error handling) so you can just use this method. I've made it an extension method for convenience.

```
//it seems 81920 is the default size in CopyTo but this can be changed
public static void CopyTo(this Stream source, Stream destination, int bufferSize = 81920)
{
    byte[] array = new byte[bufferSize];
    int count;
    while ((count = source.Read(array, 0, array.Length)) != 0)
    {
       destination.Write(array, 0, count);
    }
}
```

So you can simply do

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{       
    fu.PostedFile.InputStream.CopyTo(ms);
    ms.Position = 0;
    img = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(ms);
}
```

Comment: Your extension function does not appear to do what it claims to do. It appears to be reading and writing from destination.

Answer (score 1):

As Caboosetp mentioned, I think the correct method, (which I got from somewhere else, probably on SO) is:

```
public static void CopyTo(Stream input, Stream outputStream)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024]; // Fairly arbitrary size
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
    }
```

with:

```
Stream stream = MyService.Download(("1231"));
using (Stream s = File.Create(file_path))
{
    CopyTo(stream, s);
}
```